# How to make one widget fixed when using QSplitter

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qsplitter

There are three frames: top, middle and bottom. Whenever I resize the bottom frame, the top frame always resizes at the same time. I want to the top frame to keep its size when the bottom frame resizes. How to achieve that?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, 
    QSplitter, QStyleFactory, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        top =  QFrame(self)
        top.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        middle = QFrame(self)
        middle.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        bottom = QFrame(self)
        bottom.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter1.addWidget(top)
        splitter1.addWidget(middle)
        splitter1.setSizes([300,300])
        splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter2.addWidget(bottom)
        splitter2.setSizes([600,400])
        hbox.addWidget(splitter2)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the frames to resize independently of each other, put them all in the same splitter, like this:

```
def initUI(self):
    hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

    top = QFrame(self)
    top.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    middle = QFrame(self)
    middle.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    bottom = QFrame(self)
    bottom.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

    splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
    splitter1.addWidget(top)
    splitter1.addWidget(middle)
    splitter1.addWidget(bottom)
    splitter1.setSizes([500,300,200])

    hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
    self.setLayout(hbox)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want.